# How do universities avoid being "outmaneuvered" in removing poorly-performing faculty who bring in large research grants?

Tags: funding, teaching, lecturer, assistant-professor

Consider an "ambitious" assistant professor (junior, untenured faculty) appointed to a junior lectureship in a medicine, physical science or engineering department with the usual teaching and u/grad supervision obligations. Like all academics, he/she is entirely responsible for developing and maintaining their own personal research interests and most of the funding needed for it. This AP successfully bids for a research council grant (e.g., $500K over three years) and applies it to hire some staff and buy some high-end equipment, which is also sometimes made available to other staff and students on the usual mutual cooperation basis.

This assistant professor is soon found to be inadequate at their teaching responsibilities. As he/she is still untenured, their temporary lectureship may *theoretically* not be renewed after year 1 were their teaching performance to remain inadequate. But given the impact of losing the leader of a research commitment made by the university to a state research council over a 3 year span, and moreover seeing that the assistant professor's release would arouse ill-feeling amongst other staff with whom he/she is popular, the department head understandably is hesitant to make the dismissal.
On the other hand the department head realizes that being seen to allow bad professional habits to be tolerated simply because the academic concerned has brought in resources that benefit the whole department is only going to encourage similar maneuvers by other staff members in future.

Have universities created any mechanisms to prevent Heads of Departments arriving in this situation ?

For example:

1. Not allowing *independent* research by junior academics till they had achieved tenure after 2-3 years of good performance at teaching, u/grad supervision, laboratory & departmental administration duties and very stisfactory contributions to existing joint research programmes within the department
2. Ensuring a university department head makes all independent research proposals prepared by untenured staff, with the untenured staffmember strictly being only a research lead for such a programme. For this option to be viable the research interest pursued by any untenured staffmember must be formally established as a research group with at least 2 members of the department's faculty. This enables viable continuation of any research programmes under another properly qualified leader were the original lead researcher's lectureship to be terminated for any reason
3. Allow the junior to undertake independent research and seek their own funds. Equipment of general use purchased via the funds could be co-owned by the researcher and the department, project specific equipment remains the property of the junior and its maintenance and insurance being covered by the junior's department. A pre-nup style agreement is made for the division of grant funded equipment in the event of the junior's lectureship not being renewed. In effect, the dismissed junior must take the equipment (bar general use stuff) and staff accumulated during the incomplete programme to his/her next employer. This is no small responsibility, even to a genuinely able and honest academic. I doubt if a selfishly-ambitious type would readily take this option as it would tie them to their duties for years at a time and prevent them migrating to another appointment free-as-a-bird of any obligation to others.

In terms of preventing a vigilant head of department being outmaneuvered (or indeed even being socially 'outbraked'!) by an unscrupulously ambitious junior lecturer, I think only no. 1 of the above options is acceptable: it would be very hard for any less than adequate junior to successfully fake it over 2-3 years of serious stress-testing on the job. The drawback with this is that the junior has to put their keenest research interest on ice for a long period. They may also feel that they are really just being Shanghaied into doing donkey-work on other staff's programmes and that full freedom to do their own thing may only be a Shangri-La promise held forever before them.

The other 2 options I feel allow the possibility of upset relations amongst staffmembers (moreover in an environment that can only operate on trust) if the junior is dismissed.

Comment: I think I managed to figure out what you were trying to ask, and have therefore edited the question. I also folded in some other info from the comments. Everything else has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115716/discussion-on-question-by-trunk-how-do-universities-avoid-being-held-hostage-b).

Comment: @cag51 and others : I feel you have made so many edits that it's a different question with a different emphasis. I feel that certain realities of academic life are being occluded in the name of making this question clearer to readers - but in actuality you are just occluding the realities here and that is quite wrong.

Comment: It is your question, not ours; you may certainly modify or revert the edits if you disagree with them. That said: your original question was extremely unclear and had already accumulated both close votes and downvotes (as well as a mountain of requests for clarifications). So, if you make changes, I strongly suggest you try to clarify things; questions that remain confusing and cannot be clarified tend to be closed.

Comment: @cag51 I have rewritten it elaborately. No doubt some will stilll see things to improve in it and if so please communicate as much.

Comment: I'm extra confused now.

Comment: I find it harder than ever to really visualize the premise in real life...

Comment: @paul garrett That makes any department that you may be head of extra vulnerable to a budding Dr Z . . .

Comment: @Trunk No, your question doesn't make any sense and I am frankly baffled to what you are trying to get at. I think you'd be best suited to start a new question asking about some basic practices of departments because I think you are making a lot of assumptions that don't track with how things work, so those of us more familiar don't know what you're asking because your premises are all flawed.

Comment: What fraction of the junior academic's time was included in the budget of the original research proposal?  A $500000 grant is more than enough to "buy out" 100% of a newly-minted lecturer's time for 3 years, even including indirect costs.  If that's the case, then if the university tries to dismiss the junior academic for not fulfilling his/her teaching responsibilities, the research council might be a bit cross that the university had given the junior academic any teaching responsibilities in the first place.

Comment: @Daniel Hatton I didn't have any access to this stuff - just a 16 x 6 PhD student then. And I still don't know how these things are put together having left the groves of academia. But I'd be surprised if such a grant put *any* valuation on the junior's time because research is something each academic is supposed to be doing as part of their university employment - it's not an extra like a brief consultancy to a local company. I see no basis for the RC objecting UNLESS their clear oral understanding was that Dr Z was solely engaged for research work like a research fellow or research prof.

Comment: It wouldn't be an oral understanding, it would be specified in writing in the original research proposal: with most funding bodies, the proposal has to specify the fraction of the PI's working time that will be spent on the research project, and how much of the money paid by the research funder to the university will be used to cover the appropriate fraction of the PI's salary...

Comment: ...The EU Horizon 2020 programme demands timesheets to check that the PI really has spent the promised time on the project, but most other research funders don't, so it's quite possible for a university to sell 100% (or even 200%) of an academic's time, split across multiple grants, to research funders, yet still try to allocate some teaching work to that academic.  However, if the university then tried to dismiss the academic for poor teaching performance, that would mean a high risk of the ruse being discovered, and consequent damage to the university's reputation with research funders.

Comment: @Daniel Hatton Very illuminating. Seems like universities in their present financial model could not get by without this sale of researcher time. So a junior with inside knowledge of all this carry-on would know quite well which ropes to pull. Surprised that lecturers do not form an effective association against this slide into slavery.

Comment: 'Seems like universities in their present financial model could not get by without this sale of researcher time.'  Yeah, well, there was this thing called the Reformation, and we've never quite worked out how to replace the flow of investment capital we lost by not being allowed to sell indulgences any more.

Comment: 'a junior with inside knowledge of all this carry-on would know quite well which ropes to pull' Except that the junior would be too busy trying to spend 200% of normal full-time hours working on research projects and another 40% teaching to have any free time for pulling ropes.

Comment: @Daniel Hatton  Well, the junior I knew didn't wet his hands in the lab over 10 years from junior to senior to HoD. I'd rate his work division 40:40:15:5 for overseas travel, UK travel, phone and supervisory chats ("Well, have you got those results for me ?"). You might say he never did anything but pull ropes. Just 2 PhD supervisions completed. A few walked off. One pleaded and eventually - with wife beside him - was given a change from Dr Z's supervision; even here Z was half-credited with prize given to this student's redesigned doctorate. It happens.

Comment: For purposes of university workload and performance management, supervising Ph.D. students counts as research, not teaching, so in fact, I think we've just discovered that your question is about poor performance in (one particular aspect of) research, not about poor teaching performance at all.

Comment: @Daniel Hatton He had some serious issues in the educational side like overconfidence in module development and appreciation of curriculum structure. And all that goes with poor attention to others opinions and abrupt interventions of his own. Supervision is but one aspect of research, you say ? But surely the primary one. It's absurd to be a great salesman for research activities in a group one can't lead but still headed by oneself. His salesmanship (social as much as professional) was the only plausible reason to retain him. But the real reason was lack of will by his HoD and sen lecturer.

Answer (score 9):

Quite a lot of the context of this question seems quite specific to UK STEM, and in particular biology and medical science departments. So some things to be clear about in terms of UK STEM departments:

1. There is no tenure/untenured distinction in the UK. No academic in the UK is tenured. But all academics that have been in post for more than 2 years in the UK are protected by standard employment laws which mean you can't be dismissed without a legally valid reason. Incompetence is a valid reason, but if you going to use that reason, the individual has to be given an opportunity and support to improve, usually via a performance improvement plan, and sufficient opportunity to implement it.
2. Most universities operate a probation system, where junior academics are reviewed at 3 or 5 years, against a set of criteria, similarly to tenure in a US unversity. Common criteria might be Obtain a grant, publish a paper, get above 5 (on a 1 - 10 scale) on student feedback. However, probation has no standing in law, and "they didn't pass probation" is not a legally valid reason to dismiss someone. The process to dismiss a probationary lecturer is legally the same as to dismiss someone who has been there 20 years.
3. Few UK biology/medicine departments use much in the way of adjunct, temporary or non-permeant staff or grad students to do teaching. 90% of teaching is done by permeant lecture, senior lecturer or professor grade staff (equiv. assistant/associate/full professors in the US).
4. $500k is neither large or small, its bang-on standard size for a UKRI life-sciences grant. It's three years postdoc plus consumables. Its worth noting that the department doesn't only benefit in terms of equipment. Approximately 50% of a grant will be administrative overhead and indirect costs which goes straight to the university. When a university accepts a grant from a research council, it will usually sign an agreement that the PI on the grant will be employed for the duration of the grant. However, legally speaking a grant is always awarded to the university, not the PI, and its the university that has responsibility to ensure the research is delivered.

With that out of the way the answer to the question:
How do departments " prevent said faculty from using their large grant to outmanoeuvre efforts to dismiss them for teaching inadequacy?" is that they don't.

For starters I've never heard of anyone being sacked for inadequate teaching, irrespective of whether they have a grant or not. Perhaps if they flat out refused to do it. Or just didn't turn up for things. If anyone told me they were being dismissed for their "teaching quality", but be pretty sure that there was some other, not legally valid, real reason for the dismissal.

University departments have multiple roles, primarily education and research. But even officially, research is as important as education. The standard academic contract is 40:40:20 research:teaching:admin - teaching accounts for less than half of the duties of an academic. Given that, why would a HoD want to dismiss someone who was good and research and admin but poor at teaching? No one can excel at every facet of their job. Really successful researchers may even buy themsevles out of having to do any teaching, but we are talking about a much higher research income than $500k for that, maybe $1.5M - £2M.

Frankly speaking, while excellent teachers are rare, teaching sufficiently well that the department doesn't get in trouble is not that rare a skill, while having continuous, good, research funding is something that few people can manage.

Comment: At last a well-composed answer. I believe that you are incorrect saying that incompetence is a valid reason for dismissal. I've read it more than once that IIRC "mere incompetence is not in itself sufficient grounds for dismissal of an academic". And your (and my - aside from 1 dismissal of a theology lecturer who abandoned his priesthood) not having encountered any such competency based dismissals gives a lot of weight to this. Your breakdown of 40:40:20 looks right today. But not all those with research funding produce worthy work of course and this *should* be grounds for release also.

Comment: 40:40:20 doesn't *look* right. Its written into our contracts.

Comment: "mere incompetence is not in itself sufficient grounds for dismissal of an academic" This is true in the US where there are there is tenure. There is no tenure in the UK, and the same rules apply as any employee of any business. Those reasons are set out here: https://www.gov.uk/dismissal/reasons-you-can-be-dismissed

Comment: @IanSudbery what makes you think incompetence is not sufficient grounds for dismissal in the US? In fact it is specifically mentioned in my institution’s policies as one of the valid reasons for dismissal, the other main such valid reason being misconduct.

Comment: I have to admit I don't know the ins and outs of the rules around tenure. But my understanding was that tenure meant you could only be dismissed for misconduct or economic reasons.

Comment: @Trunk I didn't say I hadn't encounter any competency based dismiessals - I said I hadn't encountered anyone dismissed for inadequate teaching. We've just two people from our department in the last year for not having enough grants or papers. Legally these would be competency based dismissals (actually, they were both perfectly competent scientists and one was a very good teacher.)

Comment: @Ian Sudbury Sorry to hear of the two's plight. But the characters I have in mind are in a wholly different category. Once leverage of research funding (plus the social offensive efforts) was applied to saving his position, Dr Z had a solid base from which to build his research "reputation", get onto national and EU committees for that field, get more funds from these sources, build up industrial clients, get more "consultancy" from these and create PhD projects to serve these clients using a steady flow of foreign students who won't object to the low status of the work or they lose their visa

Comment: I feel as though this question/discussion is based around a logical fallacy. Either someone is sufficiently valuable to the department to justify their salary, or they're not. This is a holistic assessment: someone who manages to secure equipment the department needs may be useful, even if they're hopeless at teaching. By definition, 'holding hostage' implies that something of value is at stake.

Comment: @avid You make a valid point in that someone with a facility for obtaining funds for research may be justifiably employed in that capacity alone by a university or one of its major departments. In recent years (esp. post 2000) appointments like this are made in both small and large universities. Likewise with specialists to manage a university's overseas partner institutions. But where such appointments are made - and I see no reason why an ex-academic ought not hold such positions - the person appointed retains no academic status, though they may retain a title, e.g. Prof, if they were such.

Comment: @avid Its not quite just that. Employment law is also relevant, and may well prevent the department from getting rid an academic just because they arn't sufficient "valuble">.

Comment: @Trunk - there is nothing new about unviersities hiring staff on their research prowess, and then judging their ongoing suitability for the post primarily on that basis. And by "research prowess", I mean "ability to attract funding". Its not a post 2000 thing, its been this way, in life sciences, for at least 50 years. It sounds like your Dr. Z is doing exactly what he is hired to do. In particular "build up industrial clients, get more "consultancy" from these and create PhD projects to serve these clients" is exactly the business model unis and government would like profs to follow.

Comment: @Ian Sudbery Life science faculty are far more demure than their physical sciences counterparts. Turning "consultancy" (this is industrial donkey-work, not real deep insight consultancy) into Mickey Mouse PhDs performed by foreign students who have been no option whatever in proffering their own topics/treatments with "supervision" being done by crabby postdocs, all while their Dr Zs tour the world's conference capitals so often they become dromomaniacs - this is NOT a good educational or research environment. Neither is it what governments, staff, students or parents want univs to follow.

Comment: Whether right or wrong, none of the things you describe are in the least bit unusual. And home students would have no more opportunity to choose a topic than an overseas student. Its just standard practice for students to apply to pre-designed projects. Supervisors design sutdent projects, ask for funding for them, and if they get it, then they recruit a student. Not only that, but a PhD project that doing industry consultancy goes to the top of the queue for government funding, so it is at least what government wants. Not only that but unis are rewarded for "knowledge transfer".

Comment: @Ian Sudbery The government policy is a factor - and I suppose HoDs feel obliged to tip their hats to it. But isn't it a convenience for many academics too ? How many of them could - let alone would - embrace a whole new direction and all the PR challenges going with finding funds in industry or Wolfson-type foundations for it ? Even where a new direction is low-overhead (e.g. computational work related to scientific area), it's seldom you'd see an independent path being trod. Knowledge transfer is best effected by u/grad student placements, which is hard to gauge or credit.

Answer (score 6):

**This answer has not been updated in response to the question edit war.**

The question is confused about several things.

- It would be very unusual to get dismissed for inadequate teaching.  Grants have nothing to do with it.  The penalty for bad teaching is that you do not get a new contract.  This is distinct from dismissal.  Dismissal is used for major misconduct, such as a felony.
- University preferences are very important:

  - Some universities are quite happy for faculty to get a large grant.
    They might not require those faculty to teach at all.  Or they might
    teach very rarely.  In this case teaching quality will not be
    important.
  - Some universities renew contracts based on a combination of teaching and research.  Both must be good to get your next contract.
  - Some universities renew contracts based on teaching quality and perhaps administration, without regard to grants.
  - Some faculty teach only and are simply ineligible to apply for grants.  E.g. adjuncts.
  - Some universities cannot afford labs, so it is impossible to get a big grant of the sort that only goes to experimental research.  Most grants cannot be used to build lab space.

If you are hiring a teacher, it is always best to hire someone who wants to teach.

Comment: In most European countries, the term *dismissal* is a legal one. (Please don't confuse this term with the more colloquial meaning, i.e. summary dismissal - sending an employee out of the workplace there and then.) Dismissal letters accompany any termination of employment regardless of employee competence. This is a legal requirement so that redundancy claims or challenges to dismissal have a legal basis to proceed. So when I say dismissal, I mean the university simply does not renew the academic's contract or offer them a permanent one.

Comment: Oh, universities DO refit existing lab space with new equipment provided by grants. In fact, if the grant is adequate they may well build entirely new lab space, kit it out and hire RAs and RFs. You often see this where a large local corporation or public agency commits a large amount to a dedicated lab on a college campus close to the department associated with such research.

Comment: @Trunk Well then, consider this answer not to apply to your location.  I would have used the phrase "termination" instead of dismissal, but maybe that's how it's done in some places.

Comment: " universities DO refit existing lab space with new equipment provided by grants"  In cases I am familiar with, equipment is funded but buildings and fittings are not.  I'm sure there are exceptions.

Comment: If you are able, you might edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: *If you are hiring a teacher, it is always best to hire someone who wants to teach . . .*  This kind of comment is like saying the winner of the Champion Stakes is . . . the fastest horse on the day. You miss the point. We are dealing with human beings. Even postgraduate studies candidates will study the work of each professor they apply to, get to know his mental hobby-horses, his opinions and attitudes - then will re-enact them at interview. Such antics can only be worse when a lectureship is on offer. CVs and nice manners say nothing. Hence the need for actual work trial and termination.

Comment: @Trunk, at least in math in the U.S., I don't think it's as easy as you suggest to "fool people". The main filter is _prior_ to hiring, not after. Yes, this is somewhat in contrast to decades ago, where many people (in math) actually did not get tenure. But at that time, people often got tenure _track_ jobs straight after a PhD. Nowadays, the style is to do post-docs before applying for tenure-track jobs. I think my univ would not consider most applicants for tenure-track jobs if they'd not done postdocs. A postdoc is a "trial period" with less political overhead than not granting tenure...

Comment: @paul garrett : Math departments are very different. I mean, what lab equipment do you really need for math ? Certainly nothing significant like in sciences/engineering. I think it's also easier to see if math work contains something new and relevant or not. That said, a fluent communicator and a facility for synthesis others' work in everyday terms can seduce many of us into believing that the same person could come up with equally orginal work themselves. But  in my experience these two gifts (originination and synthesis) seldom occur in the same person.

Answer (score 6):

*Note: the question has been edited a number of times, but now it’s reasonably clear what is being asked so I’ll have a go at answering. Hope it doesn’t get rewritten again....*

> Have universities created any mechanisms to prevent Heads of Departments arriving in this situation ?

I think your question contains an interesting and somewhat subtle fallacy about universities (and about large organizations in general) that is quite common. The fallacy is that for any problem that arises, there exists a specific set of policies and mechanisms that could have prevented that problem from arising. It’s easy to believe that, and perhaps in a narrow sense there may be a bit of truth to it. (Certainly one should not discount the possible existence of such mechanisms.) But the problem is that there is such a large number of problems that can arise, that in practice it’s impossible to have an adequate number of mechanisms to deal with each and every highly specific problem, assuming all of those problems can be foreseen before they occur, which in reality they can’t.

My point is that well-functioning universities usually take a different, much higher level approach to the problem. The “mechanism” they have is simply

“Be a good university.”

This means, simply, have good leaders who understand the goals and values of the institution and believe in them, and are capable of making difficult decisions when the need arises. And those good leaders will appoint similar people under them, propagating those good qualities through the organizational hierarchy. Good institutions will be careful about whom they appoint as a department head, and have good programs to train those department heads and professional, competent staff to support them. And good universities will do many more things that make them well-equipped to deal with a crisis of the sort described in your question (like inspiring their faculty to care about teaching and not just about their own selfish interests).

At the end of the day, the problem you’re describing, although extremely specific, is just an instance of the generic problem “something has gone badly wrong”. When something has gone badly wrong, a well-run institution will have leaders in place who can handle the situation effectively and put in place solutions, even if that makes them unpopular or makes some people upset. Conversely, a badly run university with leaders who don’t understand what’s at stake and/or don’t have the backbone to make tough decisions, and with faculty who haven’t been motivated by their leaders to also believe in the mission of their university, will not deal well with a problem such as a terribly performing teacher who happens to be popular among their colleagues and controls a large grant. And this is probably true regardless of any specific “mechanisms” that may exist on paper to deal with such a specific problem.

Comment: I like this answer a lot because it gets to the important abstraction underneath the specifics. I do think that the problem the OP talks about is a common one - well funded faculty who don't put any effort into teaching because their income makes them valuable irrespective of their teaching. I just think that the university thinks this isn't such a problem because poorly taught students don't really cost them anything.

Comment: @IanSudbery thanks. My point is that well-run universities with a good institutional culture are precisely those that _do_ think it’s a problem and will try, and quite possibly succeed (especially in the case of a not-yet-tenured faculty member as in OP’s scenario), to do something about it. Although granted, if the problem is only mild and doesn’t involve an instructor who is really horribly performing, most institutions will likely tolerate it. (And yes, the mild version of not-so-great teachers who get away with it because they are excellent researchers is admittedly common.)

Comment: @Dan Romnik Well-run universities will not self-establish purely around a wonderful shared feeling to create a new centre of learning. They are the result of learning from the failures of the past as much as from striving to create a perhaps not wonderful but certainly *constructive, cooperative and fair environment for all involved*. The lessons of the past have to be discussed openly, errors acknowledged and yes clear mechanisms/monitors/checks be put in place as part of a policy to prevent specific scenarios recurring. Every working environments has temptations - leadership must monitor it.

Comment: @Trunk well, okay, best of luck getting the answers that you seek from someone else then. You’ve been rejecting any advice being offered by anyone here, rebutting every point with long and tedious comments (most of which have been deleted either by you or moderators). And you’ve misspelled my name more than once. So I think I’ll disengage at this point.

Comment: @Dan Romik I am sorry for misspelling your name. I see your position. In your field huge cost is not entailed to do serious research. And I've never heard of anyone in a math department being sublimely irresponsible with a university's reputation - maybe because in my time the number of alternatives to teaching for math PhDs were few and tight competition allows good selection. No doubt life can be good with less vigilance in that metier. Not so in sciences/eng.